# Stateless Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Im currently reading Spring in Action 3rd edition, and have been experimenting with Spring MVC.
Everything works well, until i tried to 'port' my example webapp to a stateless webapp.

To determine whether a session object is created, i placed a debugging servlet filter on **/*** URL mapping, which just print out the `req.getSession(false)`, and continue the chain.

I tried changing all of my controllers' scope to request out naiveness, but of course, session is still created on a page/controller that binds the model to the form.
I wonder how to achieve stateless Spring MVC ? Im out of luck for tutorials on this matter so far.

Comment: Why does it matter? If nothing is stored in the session there's little or no state that actually matters. Are you trying to solve a specific issue?

Comment: @Dave Newton: No, it's not a specific issue. Im just curious around the idea of how to make the simple example from the book to be totally stateless, which i read can be easier clustered.

Comment: If there's nothing in session, then replication doesn't matter, except for a minor (likely very) performance hit. It's a rare app that is totally stateless, though, in my experience.

Comment: @Dave Newton: I think i get your points now. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to have all the JSPs use

```
<%@page session="false" %>
```

else a session will be created as soon as a JSP is executed.

Comment: It's stated in here also : http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-unwanted-session-creation

Answer (score 1):

Accidental session creation is one of the most common sources of invalid bug reports in Spring Security (hence the FAQ you linked to in your comment above).

Spring Security's [debugging filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-debug) can be useful if you're having issues with session creation. It will automatically log a message when a session is created, with a stacktrace inidicating where it happened. It also provides other useful information with more human-readable output that standard log entries, so is useful in a development environment. If you're using Spring Security's namespace support, you just need to add the element

```
<debug />
```

to your configuration.

Comment: Thanks ! Goodbye to my session-debugging servlet-filter :)